# How can I block or change right click menu of my own javafx app symbol at taskbar in windows

Tags: java, windows, javafx, taskbar

[image: Related Image]

I need remove the "Close Window" which is menu item in windows at right click of taskbar program. How can I do this?

Comment: The best you can do is prevent the close operation from actually doing anything, by consuming the WindowEvent in an [onCloseRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty) handler.

Comment: Yes, I blocked my program from closing in any way using onCloseRequest handler but I can't block this windows feature. I will find different solutions. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Thi is the Windows feature applied for all the minimized applications. It's not related to JavaFX either Java itself.

Comment: Are there java libraries for this? If there isn't, how can I do this with windows features?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know any.